Effective bit shuffling function for DDoS protection
I'm working on some DDoS protection and I basically need to come up with a simple encryption function to encrypt the first few bytes of each packet. A firewall will decrypt those few first bytes and sanity check them.
Our client application will always be reverse engineered at some point after release, so this is just to prevent simple flooding and reflection attacks, but won't stop anyone who actually reverse engineers the binaries themselves. What I therefore need is a simple function with the following properties:

Input and output lengths in bytes are the same.
Every input bit affects any particular output bit for at least one combination of the other input bits
Is extremely fast to compute.
Shuffles the bits well, so decrypting is harder than reverse engineering the client binary.
Stateless

Actual standardized ciphers are overkill and might even be worse, since the system does rely completely on security by obscurity.
My idea was to have a CBC type construction with the previous encrypted byte used as a table lookup to make the function non-linear.

Build a lookup table from a shared secret during the connection handshake.
Encrypt using the formula $o_i = table[o_{i-1}] \oplus b_i$ with $o_{-1} = 0$

Then run this for two rounds where between the rounds we reverse the ciphertext bytes, so that every input bit affects every output bit.
My question: Does anyone know any better constructions, which in this case would mean faster?

With a fixed number of bytes, that seems a fair match for a fast block cipher stripped from computation of round keys, replaced by hard-coded constants. I suggest you edit the question with A) statement of the targeted number of bytes, or range for that if variable B) quantitative information for 3: data rate in byte/s and fraction of the computing power of what kind of computing gear.

I want to say that if the context allowed to add even a few bits to the frames, then adding a Message Authentication Code computed with a fixed key to each packet is another partial solution to the problem (that pure cryptography can't solve). Many anti-(D)DoS proposals revolve around authenticating packets (sometime also encrypting) at the lowest level, and that seems sound to me.

The amount of data we need to encrypt is about 12 bytes. My initial thought was to just design a simple block cipher with 12 bytes block size, but the annoying thing about is that changing the block size is trickier. I therefore decided to use a block size of 1 byte and then use some form of encryption mode.
In our DDoS attacks we typically see traffic above 3Gbit/s per server, so that's about what we need to filter. That is currently done in the kernel by an eBPF XDP hook. My implementation of that simple encryption routine mentioned in the original message can do 1.5Gbit/s per core.

Also the bytes we currently have do contain a kind of MAC, since there's a timestamp in the message, so if you modify the payload, then the decryption will probably get a timestamp that is more than the allowed seconds from the servers clock. I decided to use the timestamp instead of MAC, since it prevents some attacks where you copy over to a botnet valid captured traffic. But it also allows us to filter bad traffic with some statistical accuracy.

FPE might be used to create a 12 byte block cipher, but I'm not sure if it will fit your performance characteristics. The problem with CBC is that it requires an unpredictable IV. With your requirements w.r.t. overhead you cannot include it with the ciphertext, and encrypting a counter will also not work due to the requirement to be stateless.


CBC-type construction with the previous encrypted byte used as a table lookup

Byte-by-byte encryption goes against the stated objective of speed. And with requirements 1 and 5 (not present in standard secure byte-by-byte encryption modes), if there is a single pass over the bytes, that dramatically lowers security in the sense of requirements 2 and 4. In particular, the first produced output byte can only depend on a single input byte.

If the width of what's to encrypt is fixed, I suggest a fast block cipher stripped from it's computation of round keys, which can only make it faster. Round keys becomes hard-coded constants. They can be computed as round keys would be for the actual cipher and some secret key. For most practical ciphers it's OK to use random constants for the round keys after validating with known test vectors. That's arguably desirable in a security-by-obscurity context.
There's plethora of ciphers to choose from. For 16 bytes an obvious candidate is AES, which is hardware-assisted on any modern CPU targeting multi-gigabit/s networking. For smaller block size one option is Speck, available with block size 4, 6, 8, 12 or 16 bytes.
If a variable block size is required, we can use any Format Preserving Encryption technique to build an arbitrary-size block cipher, perhaps on top a fixed size block cipher, say AES.
Condition 2 is computationally easy to check up to hundred bytes. It's useful to make such check except for known-good block ciphers with width at least 8 bytes or so. For the byte-by-byte construction in the question, there are at most 256 permutations of the last byte, therefore for a sizable proportion of permutations in $table$ the condition is not met.

Regarding your first comment, so if you look at my original question, so I apply my CBC type construction in two rounds and the second round is executed in the opposite direction (after first reversing the bytes in the buffer). Therefore the first output byte is impacted by all the bits in the input.

@eof: yes two passes of CBC solve the diffusion problem of requirement 2 (with high probability), be it in reverse direction as in the question or (better) considering the input as a circular buffer and making a little over two passes. What I say about speed and sub-optimal cryptographic properties when the block size is 1 byte stands. E.g. in the question's example there are only 256 possible transformations of the last byte, thus it's advisable to check that condition 2 holds.

Ended up going with block ciphers and 16 byte blocks, so will require some padding on the client, but leaves room for future mitigations. Implemented a few ARX based ciphers and with reduced rounds I can get 3x the performance of the current one and quality of the scrambling is better.

@eof: since you do not need vetted or even truly secure cryptography, it's reasonable to devise one's own scheme. Here is an idea for a 128-bit block cipher that's hard to beat on speed if AES-NI is game. For 96-bit, an unbalanced 64+32 ARX Feistel cipher will be faster than Speck96.

My issue is that I actually need to run the code inside the eBPF VM in the Linux kernel, so I only have access to the byte code that it supports and whatever machine code instructions the JIT engine produces. AES-NI is not available without calling kernel cryptography methods and the overhead for a 12 byte input would already kill any performance gains. However, I'm currently at the point where I can can decrypt 80M PPS per CPU core, which is much more than what the NIC could handle, so optimization is now somewhat pointless.
